# what is difference between lazy="true" and fetch="select" in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-evaluation

The `lazy=true` attribute is enable lazy loading of the parent and child collections and same thing `fetch="select"` attribute.  Is there any difference between `lazy="true"` and `fetch="select"` in hibernate?.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes.

The `lazy` attribute tells hibernate *when* to get the children.

The `fetch` attribute tells hibernate *how* to get the children.

When you say

> The lazy=true attribute is enable lazy loading of the parent and child
>   collections and same thing fetch="select" attribute

that is flat out incorrect.  The select fetch strategy is NOT the same thing as turning lazy loading off.  In fact, [from the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching)

> Select fetching: a second SELECT is used to retrieve the associated
>   entity or collection. Unless you explicitly disable lazy fetching by
>   specifying lazy="false", this second select will only be executed when
>   you access the association.

Comment: Thanks.I have another doubt when i am reading difference resouce for Proxy fetching or "No-proxy" fetching they are called Single-Valued association.what is a single-valued association in hibernate?

Answer (score 15):

When we say `fetch="select"`, then it will always fire separate queries to retrieve the association objects even if it is `lazy ="false"`.

But when we say `lazy ="true"`, it means that it will retrieve the association objects in a separate query, but not at the time of  loading the object, but when the association is first accessed. We can do it by saying `list().size()`.

When we say `fetch="join"` it will always fire a single query to get the association objects from the database.

Answer (score 1):

To solve n+1 select problem for  n queries (parent child relationship) in hibernate we use `fetch="join"` instead of `fetch="select"` . Lazy setting decides whether to load child objects while loading the parent object. You need to do this setting respective hibernate mapping file of the parent class. `lazy="true"` means not to load the child. By default the lazy loading of the child objects is true.